# makefile - How to concatenate values using a dot?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

*Make* variable `LIST_ARGS` stores `123  abc1f` as two values

How to concatenate these two values as `123.abc1f` and store in variable `VERSION`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just:

```
VERSION = $(word 1,$(LIST_ARGS)).$(word 2,$(LIST_ARGS))
```

See [text functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html) documentation.